# Finding the dimension of the symplectic group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

How do you find the dimension of the symplectic group $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$?

$\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})\subset \operatorname{Gl}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ is the group of invertible matrices $A$ such that $\omega = A^T\omega A$, where $$\omega = \bigg(\array{0 & \mathit{Id}_n\\ -\mathit{Id}_n & 0}\bigg)$$

I have tried to find the dimension of this group by dividing a matrix $A$ in four blocks, $$A = \bigg(\array{X & Y\\ Z & W}\bigg)$$
and use the defining property to put conditions on the blocks. I find the equations $X^TZ = Z^TX$, $Y^TW = W^TY$ and $Y^TZ - W^TX = \mathit{Id}_n$. The first two are obviously independent, and I think they put $2n^2$ restrictions on the group, but how should I go about the third one?

Comment: Do you know the Lie algebra of the symplectic group?

Comment: @richard: Yes, and it should have dimension $2n^2-n$, and so also the group would have the same dimension. But I want to find it without passing from the Lie algebra, if possible.

Comment: I have no idea how to read the dimension from your three equations. By the way, the dimension should be $2n^2+n$.

Comment: Hi @23rd how can we deduce the dim of the lie algebra of the symplectic group from its def, and is it always true in general that lie group and its lie algebra have the same dim?

Comment: @Lam18373 The Lie algebra of a Lie group is given by the tangent space at the unit, so yes they always have the same dimension.

Answer (score 7):

You could directly deduce the dimension from your own equations:

1. $X^T Z = Z^T X \implies X^T Z = (X^T Z)^T$,
2. $Y^T W = W^T Y \implies Y^T W = (Y^T W)^T$,
3. $Y^T Z -W^T X = \mathbb{I}_n$.

The first two are independent constraints of the form $P = P^T$, so each gives $(n^2-n)/2$ constraints. The third is also an independent constraint, of the form $P-Q = \mathbb{I}_n$, so this gives $n^2$ constraints. This leaves $4n^2 - n^2 - (n^2-n) = 2n^2+n$ degrees of freedom.

To explicitly see that the constraints decouple, from their rather suggestive form, define the complex matrices $P=X + i Z, Q= Y + i W$. Then constraints (1) and (2) are $Im(P^\dagger P ) = 0, Im(Q^\dagger Q) =0$ respectively. Constraint (3) however becomes $Im(Q^\dagger P) = \mathbb{I}_n$.

Answer (score 3):

It helps to think of the columns of $A$ instead of the blocks of $A$.

A matrix $A$ in $SP_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ has $2n$ columns, call them $e_1,\ldots,e_n,f_1,\ldots,f_n$.  We want $A$ to satisfy $A^T\omega A = \omega$, so there are $(2n)^2$ constraints we can write down (one per entry of $\omega$):

1. $e_i^T\omega e_j = 0$
2. $f_i^T \omega f_j = 0$
3. $e_i^T \omega f_j = \delta_{ij}$ and $f_i^T \omega e_j = -\delta_{ij}$.

By alternativity and antisymmetry of the form $\omega$, there are only $n(n-1)/2$ independent equations for each of #1 and #2.

By antisymmetry, there are only $n^2$ independent constraints in #3.

These are $2n^2 - n$ total independent constraints on the $(2n)^2$ possible $2n \times 2n$ matrices.

We are left with $2n^2 + n$ real degrees of freedom, so $SP_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $2n^2 + n$.

Comment: waht does it mean that $w$ is alternative here?

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of the Lie group $G = Sp_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ is the same as that of its tangent space $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ at the origin. Linearizing the defining relation for $G$ (in your notation above, $g^t \omega g = \omega)$ gives 
$$\mathfrak{g} = \{X\in\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{R}):\, \omega X = -g^t X\}$$
Writing $X$ in terms of $n\times n$ blocks as you described gives $\dim \mathfrak{g}$.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, we have the diffeomorphism
$$Sp(2n,\Bbb R)\cong U(n)\times\Bbb R^{n(n+1)}$$
of manifolds. You may see also this [bounty question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4797239/221315).

So,
$$\dim Sp(2n,\Bbb R)=\dim U(n)+n(n+1)=n^2+n^2+n=2n^2+n.$$