# Sp(2n, R) = SL(2n, R)

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

I have proved that Sp(2n,R) is a subgroup of SL(2n,R).
But is there an equality?
If no, what counter example can do we have?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even the dimensions are different in general. We have
$$
\dim Sp(2n)=n(2n+1),\; \dim SL(2n)=(2n)^2-1.
$$
For $n=3$ we have $\dim Sp(6)=21$, but $\dim SL(4)=35$.
The dimensions coincide with the vector space dimensions of the associated Lie algebras.

References: [Finding the dimension of the symplectic group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358595/finding-the-dimension-of-the-symplectic-group)

[Dimension of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and some other Lie groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312003/dimension-of-sln-mathbbr-and-some-other-lie-groups)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So as the dimension is different this is enough to say that there is no equality. isn't it?

Comment: Yes. You know this for vector spaces. If $V=W$ then $\dim (V)=\dim (W)$. The dimension of $G$ coincides with the vector space dimension of $Lie(G)$.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of $n=1$, we have Sp$(2,\mathbb{R}) = $SL$(2,\mathbb{R})$.