# The topology of symplectic group Sp(2n)

Tags: lie-groups, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

I am reading [V. I. Arnol’d, A. B. Givental’
, Symplectic Geometry](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/arnogive.pdf) $\S$4.4 about the topology of the symplectic group Sp(2n). It is stated that

> The manifold $Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})$ is diffeomorphic to the Cartesian product of
> the unitary group $U(n)$ with a vector space of dimension $n(n+ 1)$.

And then the authors explained that

> The key to the proof is given by the polar decomposition: an invertible operator $A$ on a Euclidean space can be represented uniquely in the form of a product $S \cdot U$ of an invertible symmetric positive operator $S=\left(A A^*\right)^{1 / 2}$ and an orthogonal operator $U=S^{-1} A$. For symmetric operators $A$ acting on the underlying real space $\mathbb{R}^{2 n}$ of the Hermitian space $\mathbb{C}^n$, the operators $U$ turn out to be unitary, and the logarithms $\ln S$ of the operators $S$ fill out the $n(n+1)$ dimensional space of symmetric Hamiltonian operators.

I actually cannot quite understand what the authors are talking about here. It seems that they want to show that after the polar decomposition, a symplectic matrix $A$ is decomposed into a unitary matrix $U$ and a symmetric positive definite matrix $S$, but $U$ actually satisfies
$$
U J U^{-1} = S^{-1}A J A^{\top} S^{-\top} = S^{-1} J S^{-\top}
$$
which is not the condition of being a complex operator. So in what sense is $U$ "unitary"?

And at the same time, I don't know why "space of symmetric Hamiltonian operators" is of dimension $n(n+1)$. Does this actually mean "symmetric complex matrix" instead of Hermitian matrix?

Comment: The subgroup of the symplectic group consisting of orthogonal matrices is naturally isomorphic to the unitary group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks. I understand this but how does this fact help to establish these statements? It seems that the polar decomposition A=SU cannot guarantee that U is in Sp(2n) when A is in Sp(2n).

Comment: Hamiltonian is another (somewhat confusing if you come from physics) term for an element in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$.You can verify explicitly that the intersection of this Lie algebra with the vector space of symmetric matrices has dimension $n(n+1)$.